# search from Domain name , results showing lower case Title

Tags: google, domains, url, search, title

Search from a domain name, results in showing title in lower case (although this is not the page title been given).

Example: `jw building services (jwbuildingservices.com)`

Is it possible to make this appear in upper case ?

Comment: I see what you mean. Searching for the terms *jw building services* does return your home page with a lowercase title. I checked your source code quickly and cannot see a problem. I suggest using the Google Search Console Fetch as Google and Submit to Index. It is not immediate. It will take a few days still, however, that should help.

Comment: @closetnoc It's because he or she does not have the business name in the title tag, therefore Google is rewriting the title.

Comment: @SimonHayter Good catch! I guess I did not look close enough. I am glad you did. Cheers!!

Comment: @closetnoc just updated my answer, way over optimised basically :)

Comment: Thank you @closetnoc for your time and effort. Really appreciate. It worked :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your Google search includes the domain name, or keywords that do not exist currently in your page title. Google only rewrites titles when the search doesn't have a 'search match', in this case you do not have JW Building Services in your META Title, therefore Google is rewriting your title, and obviously, its deciding that all lower case is best.

You can't customise the search results in this manor, however you can adjust the real issue... Poor and over optimised SEO.

Your pages titles, and descriptions should be written in such as way that they are helpful to both search engines, and visitors. Currently they over optimised, which is not only not helpful to visitors, search engines dislike it too.

*Your current home page uses:*

- Title: Electrical Services : Commercial & Domestic | Electrical Testing
- Description: 24 Hour Emergency Call-outs, Commercial & Domestic, Full House Rewires, Commercial Fit-outs, Electrical Testing and Fault Finding, SWA Cable Jointing, PAT, Inspection and Testing

The above is spammy, unreadable and Google is likely to rank you lower for over optimisation. I recommend that you have your SEO guy, or company read SEO guides dated in the last 2 years, researching Google Local search results is very important, since they differ from organics, which your site seems to disregard.

*A particular setup would look something like this:*

Local Page:

- Home Page Title: Your Business Name
- Description: A short **readable sentence** mentioning your key services, and the areas you provide them too.

Organic pages:

- Services Page: Service Name in Area Name
- Description: A short **readable sentence** mentioning your the service name, followed by top features, and area name.

Comment: I have been a little slow and inattentive lately... to much going on... so it took me a while to remember to up-vote!

Comment: Thank you very much Simone Hayter for your time.  It worked perfectly.